# How to disable/hide Wordpress theme footer on all Woocommerce product category pages using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Thank you for taking the time to help me in advance!

I am trying to get a themed Wordpress website ([Mr. Tailor](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/mr-tailor-responsive-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/7292110)) with Woocommerce not display the theme footer only on the product category pages (and instead display a sticky footer widget)

[What's happening is a red line](http://itaberco.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/soft-serve/soft-serve-mixes/), which is actually the footer but I deleted the content naively thinking it would remove it entirely.

I tried to customize PHP code from a post on [WP Sites](https://wpsites.net/) on [*Remove Footer or Widgets on Specific Pages*](https://wpsites.net/web-design/remove-footer-specific-pages/), specifically the code under *Remove Footer On Home Page Only*:

```
add_action('get_footer', 'child_remove_genesis_do_footer'); 
function child_remove_genesis_do_footer() {
if (is_home()) {
remove_action('genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer');
remove_action('genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_open', 5);
remove_action('genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_close', 15);
}
}
```

I changed all mentions of `genesis` to my theme `mr_tailor`, as well as changed the conditional tag of `if (is_home())` to `if (is_product_category())` so that it reads:

```
add_action('get_footer', 'child_remove_mr_tailor_do_footer'); 
function child_remove_mr_tailor_do_footer() {if (is_product_category()) {
remove_action('mr_tailor_footer', 'mr_tailor_do_footer');
remove_action('mr_tailor_footer', 'mr_tailor_footer_markup_open', 5);
remove_action('mr_tailor_footer', 'mr_tailor_footer_markup_close', 15);
}
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't remove the footer so I am very much so doing something wrong, haha.

I have tried:

- Removing any mentions of `child` since I am not using a child theme (bad, I know––I inherited this project)
- Changing theme tag to just `site_footer`
- Making sure everything is up to date
- Asking it very politely to work

I'm using the [PHP Inserter widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/).

Can someone help me see what my eye are woefully missing? 
Thank you!

Comment: You could take a different approach. WooCommerce likely adds a body class for category pages. You could hide your footer and show your sticky footer using CSS...

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your response! Do you mean to hide the footer site-wide and instead show on Unfortunately because of my lack of knowledge, I didn't think I could apply

Comment: (sorry, hit enter thinking it would break the line but nope, submitted prebious comment early :/ ) From what I can see on the back-end of product category pages I cannot edit/insert any CSS to hide the theme footer on those specific pages, but rather customize the theme which affects the entire site. I can state `site-fooder` to `display:none` but I only want the footer to be hidden on just the product category pages.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my original comment, you could use CSS for this instead. By default, WordPress will add classes to the body of the HTML document. WooCommerce extends these classes. Using a test site I have, if I inspect element on a product category page, I can see some extra classes have been added. One of those classes is `tax-product_cat`. That is what you will want to target. So, using CSS, you could do the following to hide the footer on product category pages (assuming site-footer is the ID and not the class).

`.tax-product_cat #site-footer { display: none; }`

You could also get a sticky footer to display based on this.

`.tax-product_cat #sticky-footer { display: block; }`

[image]